# How to conditionally render an html page based on the browser

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, feature-detection

I am working on a website.  We do not want to waste time or resources trying to optimize for internet explorer at the moment.  How do I detect if a page has been opened in IE and then conditionally render a browser not supported page instead of the actual homepage.

I thought about html conditional comments but they are no longer supported as of IE10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `window.navigator.userAgent` to detect IE browser. You could refer to the JavaScript code below:

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
if (trident > 0) {
    console.log('Your browser is IE');
}
```